# How to see integration test coverage in Sonarqube 6.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

As of now with Sonarqube LTS (5.6), this doc (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) can be used to import generic test report in sonarqube . Also this property (sonar.genericcoverage.itReportPaths) can be used to see integration test coverage in Sonarqube. But with 6.2 it is deprecated.

Only way to import generic coverage in 6.2 is through this property ( sonar.coverageReportPaths) as explained in this doc : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data . There is no mention of integration test reports separately.

Please help me to identify which property to use in Sonar 6.2 for integrating integration test coverage with Sonarqube 6.2 or it it possible also ?

Thanks
Nikhil

Answer (score 3):

In 6.2 there is no longer a differentiation between unit tests, integration tests, smoke tests, ...

Now they're imported and rolled into Coverage, with no distinctions about *how* lines are covered. So use `sonar.coverageReportPaths`.

Comment: Thanks G.Ann for your answer . That means , the property sonar.jacoco.itReportPath will also become obsolete and should not be used . Details about this property has been documented here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project